# ABAP type pool: program with type code TYPP but with name longer than five characters

Tags: abap

We are writing a tool in Java that parses and transforms ABAP code. We therefore have no intention to write new ABAP code but our tool has to handle all of ABAP, even obsolete statements.  Furthermore, I'm not an ABAP expert.

ABAP programs can use type groups, introduced by key word TYPE-POOL.  Names of type groups have a maximal length of five (internally eight, if you count the prefix "% C"), their type code is TYPP.  In the past, relying on these assumptions worked well for us.

Recently, we see ABAP programs with type code TYPP but with name longer than 5, e.g., 'OIA===========================P'. Furthermore, for each of those, there is another, empty object with same name but type code INCL. These new objects are referenced only if a regular type group is, too.

These new objects may be internal ones and irrelevant for us - I haven't seen any reference to them in the ABAP Keyword Documentation. On the other hand, they are confusing us because we see them.

Can someone explain to me the meaning of these objects and point me to some documentation?

Edit: Here examples from an EHP7 for SAP ERP 6.0 system

An example object.  Entries in D010INC look fine:
[image: example object w/o use of type pool mrm]

The same object now using type pool mrm.  Where do the additional includes come from?
[image: example object with use of type pool mrm]

Comment: First of all, tell us **where** (in what piece of code) do you see them, secondly, in what **context** do you see them. In conjunction with what statements? What is their function in those context? Give some additional references, maybe screenshots. Otherwise your question is too abstract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These objects are introduced through inclusions, extensions and switched objects. To read along:

- Check type pool `MRM`, type `mrm_idoc_data_ers` - that type contains a statement to include `rmrm_idoc_data_ers_sbo`. A similar include statement pulls `rmrm_upd_arseg_nfm` into `mrm_upd_arseg`. That explains the last two lines. Your parser should have caught that.
- `RMRM_IDOC_DATA_ERS_SBO` contains an enhancement point named `RMRM_IDOC_DATA_ERS_SBO_02` that belongs to an enhancement spot `ES_RMRM_IDOC_DATA_ERS_SBO`. Similarly, `RMRM_UPD_ARSEG_NFM` contains an enhancement point `RMRM_UPD_ARSEG_NFM_01` that belongs to the enhancement spot `ES_RMRM_UPD_ARSEG_NFM`.
- For `ES_RMRM_IDOC_DATA_ERS_SBO`, an enhancement implementation named `ISAUTO_MRM_RMRM_IDOC_DATA_ERS` exists. For `ES_RMRM_UPD_ARSEG_NFM`, an implementation named `/NFM/MM_RMRM_UPD_ARSEG_NFM` exists. That explains the references ending with `=E`
- The implementation `ISAUTO_MRM_RMRM_IDOC_DATA_ERS` is located in the package `ISAUTO_MRM`. The implementation `/NFM/MM_RMRM_UPD_ARSEG_NFM` is located in the package `/NFM/MM`. That explains the references ending with `=P`. Obviously, these references are not generated for every package:
- The package `ISAUTO_MRM` is controlled by the switch `AM_ERS`, the package `/NFM/MM` is controlled by the switch `/NFM/MM`. That explains the references ending in `=S`.

Ultimately, these references can be used to determine which programs need to be re-generated when the state of a switch is changed.

Comment: Of what types are these `*===={P,S,E}` objects? I do not find them in table `TADIR`

Comment: As far as I can see, these are only pseudo-includes that do not have an object catalog entry.